# Ho to get multi array in dynamic

Tags: php

Array Structure:

```
array (
  'payee_id' => 2381,
  'items' => 
          array (
            300 => 
                array (
                    'item_id' => 300,
                    ' price' => 50,
                ),
            372 => 
                array (
                      'item_id' => 372,
                      'price' => 90,
                ),
          ),
)
```

I'm trying to get the `item_id` and `price` with dynamic.

Code

```
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    Log::debug($value[300]['price']);
}
```

With code above, I could able to get the key `300` `price`, but i need to get the key `372` too.

Comment: what... surely.. just `$value['item_id']`? using `empty()` or `isset()` to check before logging..

Comment: something like `foreach($value as $newVal){ Log::debug($newVal['price']); }`?? inside your loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more solution by using `foreach()`

```
<?php
foreach($data as $key => $value) { // if `$data` equal to $data['items'] as you mentioned in your question `Log::debug($value[300]['price']);`
    foreach ($value as $finalValue) { // loop for inner array
        echo $finalValue['price']."<br/>"; // print price in new line
    }   
}
?>
```